# Focus li which is in center of page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create form like typeForm. 
You can find example here https://showroom.typeform.com/to/DYJEHG

I sucessfully implemented design but problem is i want to focus li which comes in vertical center of page. 
I tried everything but fails, There is no tutorial on google how we can do this. 
Please help.

Comment: please put your code. what have you done?

Comment: What do you mean by "focus"? If you mean that you want to automatically scroll down to an element that is initially off the bottom of the screen, try `.scrollIntoView()`.

Comment: Please include the code that you have tried so far, so we can help you debug or improve it. That's how Stackoverflow works.

Comment: I found something here. Let me apply it https://jsfiddle.net/fa90a23u/

Answer (score 1):

If i am not wrong, you want the form field to be in the center(horizontally and vertically) and to be full page, right?

Here's a working example of what you might be looking for: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZewEMM

In that case,
**To focus on one input field per scroll:**
Use this small plugin called **[fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)**. This will allow you to have focus on one input field per scroll. It's really easy to use, check it out!
Here an example of your form with fullpage.js:

```
<form method="post" action="">

  <div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section formfield">
      <div>
        FULL NAME<br/>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section formfield">
      <div>
        EMAIL<br/>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section formfield">
      <div>
        MESSAGE<br/>
        <input type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Notice that, for ease of use and to avoid confusion, i have not used `<li>`.

You can also control the colors of each field section easily via JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#fullpage').fullpage({
    sectionsColor: ['#f0f0f0', '#cccccc', '#f0f0f0'], // section colors
    css3: true,
    scrollingSpeed: 1000
  });
});
```

**To center the form field vertically and horizontally:**
Use Flexbox by wrapping the form field elements inside a div. Here's a sample CSS code:

```
.formfield > div {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: center;
}
```

Let me know if this helps, and also feel free to ask if you find anything vague in my answer.